# Need help centering this navigation menu css

Tags: html, css, menu

I need help centering this navigation menu. I am fairly new to css and need to finish a school project

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
<link rel="icon" " href="favicon.ico" />
<style>
ul.menu{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;padding-top:6px;padding-bottom:6px;}
li.menu{display:inline;}
a:link,a:visited.menu{font-weight:bold;color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#35BFD7;text-    align:center;padding:6px;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase;}
a:hover,a:active.menu{background-color:#3597FF;}
body{background-image:url('background.gif');background-size:100% 100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class=menu>
<li class=menu><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
<li class=menu><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
<li class=menu><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
<li class=menu><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `text-align:center` to your `<ul>`. This will center all `display:inline` and `display:inline-block` elements.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UrtfQ/)

```
ul.menu {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the text to be centered in the page, not just the inline music, just add

```
body {
  text-align: center;
}
```

wrap the ul in a div if you want, and center that instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Website</title>
<link rel="icon" " href="favicon.ico" />
<style>
ul.menu{list-style-type:none;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;
width: 334px;padding:0;padding-top:6px;padding-bottom:6px;}
li.menu{display:inline;}
a:link,a:visited.menu{font-weight:bold;color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#35BFD7;text-    align:center;padding:6px;text-decoration:none;text-transform:uppercase;}
a:hover,a:active.menu{background-color:#3597FF;}
body{background-image:url('background.gif');background-size:100% 100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class=menu>
<li class=menu><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
<li class=menu><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
<li class=menu><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
<li class=menu><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your text centered horizontally, then yes 'text-align: center' should do the trick.

However, if you want all of your list items to display beside each other in a line, then you will need to specify:

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```